# public staticなViewを使用することは、必ずしもよくないことですか？

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

AndroidStudioでViewをstaticにすると、メモリリークの危険性があるために、ワーニングが返されてしまいます。
これは、以下の条件のような特殊なViewであっても使うべきではないでしょうか？

・アプリ上で一つしか存在しなえない。複数同時に存在する可能性がない。
・アプリ実行中常に表示される。また、TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAYに設定されており非表示にすることはない。

常に参照され続けるために、メモリリークについては考えなくていいと考えています。
なにか使用してはいけない理由があるのであれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。
使用しても問題ないのであれば、注意点などを教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 英語版スタックオーバーフローで同様の質問かあったため、自己?解決しました。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107165/is-it-a-good-idea-to-declare-static-view-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static`フィールドで`View`のインスタンスを保持してよいかどうかは、その`View`を構築するときに使用した`Context`の種類に依存します。

`View`およびそのサブクラスのコンストラクタは`Context`型の引数を持っていますが、例えば`Activity`用のレイアウトXMLを使って`View`のツリー階層を定義した場合、`View`のコンストラクタ引数にはその`Activity`のインスタンスが渡されます。
（[`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)も[`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context)のサブクラスのひとつです）

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#public-constructors

この`Context`インスタンスは、`View`のフィールド`mContext`に **強参照** として保持されます。

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java

しかし、Androidの`Activity`は、画面遷移や構成変更などに伴って破棄・再生成される可能性があり、アプリケーションのプロセスの寿命よりもライフサイクルは短くなります。そのため、もし`Activity`のインスタンスを`View`の構築時に`Context`として使う場合、その`View`のライフサイクルは`Activity`と同じにする必要があり、`static`フィールドに保持することはできません。
もし`Activity`が破棄された後（`Activity.onDestroy()`が呼ばれた後）も`View`を保持し続けてしまうと、単にその`Activity`がメモリリークするだけではなく、未定義の **異常動作** を引き起こす原因になります。

- [アクティビティの概要  |  Android デベロッパー  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities?hl=ja)

一般的に、`Activity`と`View`のライフサイクルを一致させたほうが設計が簡単かつ堅牢になりますが、どうしても`View`インスタンスを`static`フィールドに保持したい理由がある場合、[`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application)を`Context`として使って`View`を構築する手があります。`Application`のライフサイクルはアプリケーションのプロセスとほぼ同じであり、またAndroidにはアプリケーション終了の概念がないので、`Application`を使って生成した`View`であれば`Activity`のライフサイクルとは無関係に保持し続けることができます。`Context.getApplicationContext()`メソッドを使うことで、`Activity`など任意の`Context`から`Application`のインスタンスを取得することができるので、これを使って`View`を構築します。

ただし、`Application`を使って`View`を構築すると、外観スタイル（テーマ）が適用されない、`DialogFragment`を利用できない、などのデメリットもあります。そういった問題を避けるために、`View`の構築時は`Activity`をbase contextとして設定した[`MutableContextWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/MutableContextWrapper)を使っておき、`Activity`の破棄`onDestroy()`と再生成`onCreate()`のタイミングで`MutableContextWrapper.setBaseContext()`を使って差し替える方法もあります。